# Git Upload Via Command line

Tags: git, github

I've already written some code and now wish to upload it to git hub via command line.

Am I correct in the process?

Set up a project on git hub via browser.

Go to my projects directory and perform via command line:

```
git init
```

Next perform:

```
git add *
```

Then:

```
git commit -am "first commit'
```

Then what is the difference between:

```
git push origin master
git remote add origin
```

Also, I've followed a [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) about using two accounts, how would this integrate with the above steps every time I wish to commit?

The tutorial stated:

```
git remote add origin git@github-mySecondUser:mySecondUser/test.git
```

How would it work with push?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git remote add origin ...`adds a remote git repo and names it 'origin'. If you don't execute this command, you won't have any remote configured for your local repo, and you will thus not be able to push to the remote github repo.

`git push origin master` pushes the commits of your local master branch to the remote repo named 'origin'.

See http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes for more information.